# What is the difference between "I want" and "I do want"?

Tags: meaning

Reading some books and posts I noticed that there are some semantice differences between constructions described in the title of this post.
Could someone help me to find out what are the real difference and in which situations are better to use appropriate constructions?

I would be very grateful to hear the correct answer.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The *do* is for emphasis; see e.g. this BBC piece on [the emphatic 'do'](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/ask_about_english/071112/), but if you can narrow down your question to one aspect of it, it may be answerable here. For additional guidance on how to use this site, I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Comment: Choster's link gives a good explanation about the two uses of  emphatic  do, emphasis and contradiction. If you google for "emphatic do" you get a lot more links and even exercises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two (at least) contexts for the emphatic *do*:

To counter the mistaken notion that *do not* applies:

**You don't seem to want to see this film.

--I *do* want to see it, just not tonight.**

To apprise the listener to take special notice of what is being said:

**I do want to inform you, bears have been seen near this campground.**