# Auxiliary DO in "I do love you"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I am wondering about the meaning and use of DO in "I do love you". Is it just an emphatic use that means "I really love you! I love you so!" or a contraditory statement:

- You don't love me!
- You're wrong, I do love you!

Comment: Related question, [What is the difference between “I want” and “I do want”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285238/what-is-the-difference-between-i-want-and-i-do-want/285249#285249) and [How to add emphasis to a modal verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/how-to-add-emphasis-to-a-modal-verb). Please take a look at the first comment and answer of the first linked question. The second link might be interesting to you.

Comment: Related: 1. [Use of “do” in affirmative statements](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24521/use-of-do-in-affirmative-statements) 2. [“did shoot” vs “shot”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323/did-shoot-vs-shot) 3. [*The word ‘do’ emphasises the main verb in this context, but not necessarily in a positive way. It can bear either a positive or a negative/opposing emphasis, depending on context, or on what follow:*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/151275/44619)

Comment: 4. [“Do” as a tense marker](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285262/do-as-a-tense-marker)

Comment: "I do love you, BUT . . .." That "but"  is one possibility I just thought of! In other words, the person is saying "I love you," but there are extenuating circumstances or factors which might diminish that love. They could range from ". . . but I'm also in love with her," or ". . . but some things have to change if we're going to remain a couple." The ol' "I do love you, but"!